# Auto scroll hacia un div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando realizar un autoscroll hacia el siguiente div. Quiero conseguir que cuando se detecte el evento de scroll pase automáticamente al siguiente div, tanto para arriba como para abajo. Mi mayor problema es cuando el scroll es hacia arriba, se vuelve loco.

Tengo varios div, que ocupan el alto de la pantalla. Quiero que cuando el usuario haga scroll, automáticamente cambien al div inmediatamente superior o inferior, dependiendo de hacia donde se dirija el scroll. Es como el efecto de las one page, que va cambiado automáticamente cuando pinchas en el menu, pero sin pinchar, solo detectando el scroll.

Aquí mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var initialScroll = 0;

  $(this).scroll(function() {

    var lastPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (lastPosition < initialScroll) {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#primero").position().top
        },
        'slow');
      console.log('baja el valor');
    } else {
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#segundo").position().top
        },
        'slow');
      console.log('sube');
    }

    initialScroll = lastPosition;

  });


});
```

```css
html, body, .container{
  height:100%;
}
.container>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first">
      <div class="letras">

        <h1 class="titulo-salud">h1</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="division" id="primero">
        <div class="ad">

        </div>
        <div class="sa">

        </div>
        <div class="dk">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Cierra first-->
    <div class="second" id="segundo">
      <h1 class="titulo-salud">h2</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Cierra second-->
  </div>
  <!--Cierra container-->
</body>
```

Comment: Hola Rafael. No está claro lo que te pasa y lo que necesitas. Puedes explicarlo mejor, ejemplificando si es posible? Un saludo

Comment: Pues tengo varios div, que ocupan el alto de la pantalla. Quiero que cuando el usuario haga scroll, automaticamente cambien al div inmediatamente superior o infererior, dependiendo de hacia donde se diriga el scroll. Es como el efecto de las one page, que va cambiado automaticamente cuando pinchas en el menu, pero sin pinchar, solo detectando el scroll

Comment: He añadido un poco de CSS para que se pueda ver el problema. Te recomiendo que leas cómo crear un [mcve], para ver cómo añadir código de manera más efectiva.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es la animación, como el evento `scroll` se está ejecutando tantas veces seguidas la animación se bloquea y es lo que provoca el resultado que has visto, lo que se me ha ocurrido es parar la animación cada vez que se termine de ejecutar, de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var initialScroll = 0;

    $(this).scroll(function() {
        var lastPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (lastPosition < initialScroll) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".first").position().top
            }, 'slow', function(){
                $('html, body').stop(true);
            });
        }else{
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".second").position().top
            }, 'slow', function(){
                $('html, body').stop(true);
            });
        }

        initialScroll = lastPosition;
    });
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
  height:100%;
}

.container>div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="letras">
            <h1 class="titulo-salud">h1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="division" id="primero">
            <div class="ad">

            </div>
            <div class="sa">

            </div>
            <div class="dk">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Cierra first-->
    <div class="second" id="segundo">
        <h1 class="titulo-salud">h2</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Cierra second-->
</div>
<!--Cierra container-->
```

Comment: Funciona!! ya sube y baja aunque la animación no es muy fluida... quizas deba tomar otro camino para realizar esta acción. Aún así muchas gracias, le voy a dar una vuelta a ver si consigo mejorarlo.